# Revmob Ads in IOS Application

Tags: iphone, integration, ios, revmob

I am trying to integrate Revmob Ads in my IPhone Application but after two or three time, i am getting time out message in my console and after it nothing is happening even if i place NSlog in delegate function.

Can any one help me to solve issue of time out?
And i am using Full screen Ads.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Usually you get no ads due to lack of ads for you device or due to time out on the connection with their server.

If you have no ads for you device you can force to show the ads with [Testing mode](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios#testing-mode):

```
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"your AppID"];
[RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithAds;
```

If your problem is timeouts first you need to check if your internet connection is ok.
This kind of timeouts are a temporary issue and should be gone in minutes, if this problem
persists I recommend to contact revmob.

Comment: I am getting ads in Testing mdoe but getting error in production mode. It is not going since last 3 days. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"Your Id"];
[RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithAds;
```